# There are $n$ balls. Investigate the independence of the events $A_j =$ { number j appeared in the first j draws }, where: $j = 1, 2, . . . , n$.

Tags: probability, independence

From an urn containing $n$ balls numbered from $1$ to $n$, one ball is drawn and then returned to the urn. Then that event is repeated.

Investigate the independence of the events $A_j =$ { number j appeared in the first j draws }, where: $j = 1, 2, . . . , n$.

I know that for evens $A_i$ and $A_j$ to be independent, it has to be true that: $P(A_i) \cdot P(A_j) = P(A_i \wedge A_j)$.

I think that is can be assumed that: $P(A_i) = n^i - (n-1)^i$. It is so, because we need to subtract all the sequences created by choosing each time one of of $n-1$ balls (because we can't choose the one with number i) from all of the sequences possible (created by choosing each time one of of $n$ balls).

Now, I don't know how calculate $P(A_i \wedge A_j)$. We need to place those $2$ numbers in $2$ draws (at least), but it's hard since the largest number where we can put $i$ is $i$ and for $j$ it's $j$. I don't know how to catch the idea of putting those two in the sequence of draws in correct way. Even if I inverse those possibilities, as I did with $P(A_i)$, it is hard to tell where I can choose one of $n-1$ balls and where I can choose one of $n-2$ balls.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that is can be assumed that: $(_)=^−(−1)^$

I believe you meant the number of ways in which the desired event can happen. You need to divide by $n^i$ for it to be the probability.

> Now, I don't know how calculate $(A_i ∧ A_j)$.

If you consider the complement of this, we have three possibilities. (Without the loss of generality, we can assume $i < j$).

1. $A_i^c \land A_j^c$

The number of ways this can happen is $(n-2)^i \cdot (n-1)^{j-i}$. For the first $i$ draws, we exclude balls with numbers $i$ and $j$. Thereafter, we exclude only balls with $j$.

2. $A_i^c \land A_j$

The number of ways this can happen is $(n-1)^i \cdot (n)^{j-i}$.

3. $A_i \land A_j^c$

The number of ways this can happen is $(n-1)^j$.

To get the probabilities, we need to divide by $n^j$ in each of the three cases. Can you take it from here?